# Which 'condition' fits "‘basis’ or condition on which the benefit was transferred"?

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales

Paul Davies. [*JC Smith's The Law of Contract* (2018 2 ed)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Smiths-Law-Contract-Paul-Davies/dp/0198807813/ref=dp_ob_title_bk). p. 465

> [image]

Which of these three homonyms fit the 'condition' colored in green beneath? p. 449.

> [image]

Comment: What makes you think it must be one of those 3?

Comment: @Greendrake Because the book colored in green, which is what it does for terms defined in the back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why was 'consideration' embraced to mean 'failure of consideration', when this would be better termed as 'failure of basis'?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/39309/why-was-consideration-embraced-to-mean-failure-of-consideration-when-this-w)

Comment: @ohwilleke Not a duplicate. We're discussing different meanings of consideration.